# The Baum Connes Conjecture - the approach using spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology

In [this](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0131/assembly.pdf) article James Davis and Wolfgang Lück introduce a approach using spectra to formulate the Baum Connes Conjecture for a discrete group $G$. In order to do so, they construct a functor 
$$\mathbb{K}^{top} :Or(G) \rightarrow \text{SPECTRA}$$
where $Or(G)$ denotes the orbit category with homogeneous spaces $G/H$ as objects and $G$-maps as morphisms. We have $\pi_*(\mathbb{K}^{top}(G(H)) \cong K_*(C_r(H)$. If $H$ is a finite subgroup, the same is true for the equivariant Kasparov group $KK^G(C_0(G/H),\mathbb{C})\cong K_*(C_r(H)$.

I want to show that the equivariant homology theory $H_*(-,\mathbb{K}^{top})$ induced by $\mathbb{K}^{top}$ and $KK^G(C_0(-), \mathbb{C})$ agree on the category of proper finite $G$-CW-complexes and then by taking limits on all proper $G$-CW-complexes. With what I mentioned before I need to construct a natural transformation between both functors. Since i am fairly new to both spectra and $KK$-theory I am having a hard time finding a way to connect the two. I would just like to get the basic idea and work out the details myself.

Tahnk you